# datatables under tree structure in jsf core/ primefaces

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, tree, datatable, primefaces

I am stuck in a rather weird situation.

I have a requirement in which i need a tree structure to define a list of elements. And when we click on any of those elements in a tree. it should expand the section below it to show 2 side by side datatables which are linked to that element.

I can use JSF 2.0 core or even primefaces 3.1.

Is it possible ??

Could anyone please help ... any suggestions would be appreciated.

**Updated**

My model is something like :

```
class Shop{
    boolean isoperational;
    String name;
    List<Item> items;
    List<boolean> itempresent;
    List<Employee> employees; 
}
```

I need the name of the shop on the tree node along with the isoperational checkbox;
And when we click on that node it should open 2 datatables.

- One containing the List of items along with itempresent checkbox.
- Other containing the List of employees.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Edited per your response (if i understand you correctly). Note that this is written from head so some attribute names might differ. The point is to set an active collection from your treetable depending on which row is clicked. An ID is set via the actionListener, then the action sets mycontroller.activeCollection to the list you want to show. Then the datatable is rerendered via normal post or ajax with values depending on which row you clicked.

Markup

```
<p:treeTable value="#{myController.treenode}" var="item">
    <p:column>
        <h:commandLink action="#{myController.setActiveShop}" value="set">
            <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{myController.shipName}" value="#{item.shop.name}"/>
        </h:commandButton>
    </p:column>
</p:treeTable>

<p:dataTable value="#{myController.activeShop.items" rendered="#{!empty myController.activeShop}" var="item">
   <p:column>#{item.name}</p:column>
</p:datatable>

<p:dataTable value="#{myController.activeShop.employees" rendered="#{!empty myController.activeShop}" var="item">
   <p:column>#{item.name}</p:column>
</p:datatable>
```

Controller

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped // Or @SessionScoped... something that can cache lists, not sure how this would be done with requestscope
public class MyController{
    private List<Shop> shopList; // Set this from a datasource. Or use only shopTree below to store your shops..
    private Shop activeShop;
    private String shopName;
    private TreeNode shopTree; // Generate this from shopList

    // insert getters and setters

    private setActiveShop(){
        for(Shop s : shipList)
            if(s.getName().equals(shopName)
                activeShop = s;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that it doesnt work. I need to display something(outputText and checkboxes) on the treenode and clicking it should open the data tables.

Comment: Do you want 2 datatables in total, or per tree node? If the first alternative, just make them below the treeTable with value set to a collection in your bean. Add a commandLink or similar to the treeTable that sets the collection that the datatable is connected to dynamically, with or without ajax.

Comment: :thanks for reply. I need two datatables per tree node. I have also updated the question.

Comment: Thanks for the effort but Aren't the datatables in your solution fixed, that is it will be 2 in number, always . What if i click on 2 tree nodes. It should display 4 datatables(2 tables per node click , and both nodes should remian expanded). I havent checked the solution you provided but it seems it will always show just 2 datatables, as the datatables are placed outside the treeTable tag

Comment: Yes, I assumed you wanted 2 fixed datatables since they were outside the treeTable. My solution has exactly one selected shop, which data is shown in the datatables. Otherwise you'd have a to replace activeShop with activeShopList and map an <ui:repeat> to it, containing datatables. An easier solution would be to have the datatables directly in the treetable